# disable a UIButton until there is text in the UITextField

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton, uitextfield

How do i disable a UIButton until there is text in the UITextField. The code i have doesn't seem to work.

```
    if ([nameTextField.text isEqualToString: @""]) {
            [myButton setEnabled:NO];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I wrote a small blog post here about it: http://blog.tarams.com/?p=339

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Keep the button disabled. Implement the UITextFieldDelegate and implement the method:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
```

Check the length of the text in the textField and if it is greater than 0, enable the button.

Comment: This didn't work for me (my text field started out as first responder, so it was never called). Also, it doesn't work when a user enters text, then deletes it all. I used code from @kingthong's blog post to make this work (code below).

Answer (score 10):

Here's the code from [kingthong's blog post](http://blog.tarams.com/?p=339), which worked for me:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.saveButton setEnabled:NO];

    [[self myTextField] becomeFirstResponder];
    [myTextField addTarget:self 
                    action:@selector(textFieldDidChange)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
}

- (void)textFieldDidChange
{
    if ([self.myTextField.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        [self.saveButton setEnabled:NO];
    }
    else {
        [self.saveButton setEnabled:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer, best one I could find!

Answer (score 1):

First disable the button then use this:

```
if (![nameTextField.text isEqualToString: @""]) {
            [myButton setEnabled:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it. Try this,

```
if ([nameTextField.text isEqualToString: @""] == TRUE) {
    [myButton setEnabled:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would double check to make sure that the if statement is being entered - sometimes things can be a little tricky with outlets.

Another way you could achieve similar results is to use the following methods.

```
– addTarget:action:forControlEvents:
– removeTarget:action:forControlEvents:
```

Answer (score 1):

First check that your UITextField and UIButton are connected with interface builders UITextField and UIButton or not ?

And also write your code in below method :

`- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;`

Answer (score 0):

set it disabled at allocation time and then use textField delegate method with condition .

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textfield {
 if(yourButton isEqual:@"") {
    yourButton.enabled = NO;
 }else {
    your.enabled = YES;
 }
```

}